# Button can't be clicked during automation

Tags: protractor

I am trying to click a button which is displayed/visible/present.

When doing it manually, user was able to click the button.
If the test was executed, you will notice that it is trying to click the button, but nothing is happening.

I also tried to put a very long wait and tried to click it manually during automation.
But, when clicking it, nothing also happens.

I cannot share the site since it is in a proxy.

This is the HTML of the button and it looks normal:

```
<a class="x-btn x-unselectable x-box-item x-toolbar-item x-btn-default-small" style="min-width: 75px; right: auto; left: 328px; top: 0px; margin: 0px;" hidefocus="on" unselectable="on" role="button" aria-hidden="false" aria-disabled="false" id="button-1011" tabindex="-1" data-componentid="button-1011">
    <span id="button-1011-btnWrap" data-ref="btnWrap" role="presentation" unselectable="on" style="" class="x-btn-wrap x-btn-wrap-default-small ">
        <span id="button-1011-btnEl" data-ref="btnEl" role="presentation" unselectable="on" style="" class="x-btn-button x-btn-button-default-small x-btn-text    x-btn-button-center ">
            <span id="button-1011-btnIconEl" data-ref="btnIconEl" role="presentation" unselectable="on" class="x-btn-icon-el x-btn-icon-el-default-small  " style=""></span>
            <span id="button-1011-btnInnerEl" data-ref="btnInnerEl" unselectable="on" class="x-btn-inner x-btn-inner-default-small">Save</span>
        </span>
    </span>
</a>
```

Code:

```
global.elmCBSave = element.all(by.cssContainingText('span', 'Save')).last();

it('should click the Save button.', function() {
    global.elmCBSave.click();
});
```

I also tried using browser.executeSrcipt, this is working when executed thru console:

```
browser.executeScript('$(".x-btn-inner.x-btn-inner-default-small:eq(3)").click()')
```

Comment: And where is the test code?

Comment: the code is pretty much given so I didn't include it. please see updated question.

Comment: Shouldn't you 'click' on the anchor instead of on the span? `element(by.id('button-1011'))`

Comment: I just tried clicking the anchor, nothing happens as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can try.

Be sure to pass `done` into your callback and handle the returned promise from the click event

```
it('should click the Save button.', function(done) {
    global.elmCBSave.click().then(function(){
        done();
    });
});
```

Also, I tend to put an expected condition to wait for element to be clickable: http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.elementToBeClickable

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
// Waits for the element with id 'abc' to be clickable.

it('should click the Save button.', function(done) {
    browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable($('#abc')), 5000).then(function(){
        global.elmCBSave.click().then(function(){
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Also, be sure you are selecting the correct element. Many times, I would have to click an `<a>` tag or something like that within/above my element identifier.

Comment: Still not able to click the button.

Comment: Yup, my element is pointed to the "Save" text with "span" tagging, which is the most inner part of the button

Comment: already tried it as well, as suggested by Tom (comment section), but is not working

Comment: @PaulCo, so you pointed to the `<a>` tag in conjunction with waiting for the element to be clickable? Sorry, im out of ideas if that doesnt work...